# How to fix error on glog install on Windows when setting up expo ios

Tags: ios, bash, react-native-ios, windows-subsystem-for-linux, glog

Error on installing glog when running `pod install` on Windows 10. I am trying to use Expo to test an iOS app from Windows.

In the error log I am finding `Syntax error: newline unexpected (expecting ")")` is being raised when running `react-native\scripts\ios-configure-glog.sh`. I have WSL.

I have updated Ruby as per [How to fix pod install error glog is too old or missing react native ios in windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58376586/how-to-fix-pod-install-error-glog-is-too-old-or-missing-react-native-ios-in-wind). I don't know the ins and outs of Cocoapods sufficiently to be confident fix the syntax error. Please help!

**Error log**

```
$>pod install

Installing unimodules:
 expo-app-loader-provider@8.0.0 from ../node_modules/expo-app-loader-provider/ios
 expo-constants@8.0.0 from ../node_modules/expo-constants/ios
 expo-error-recovery@1.0.0 from ../node_modules/expo-error-recovery/ios
 expo-file-system@8.0.0 from ../node_modules/expo-file-system/ios
 expo-font@8.0.0 from ../node_modules/expo-font/ios
 expo-keep-awake@8.0.0 from ../node_modules/expo-keep-awake/ios
 expo-linear-gradient@8.0.0 from ../node_modules/expo-linear-gradient/ios
 expo-location@8.0.0 from ../node_modules/expo-location/ios
 expo-permissions@8.0.0 from ../node_modules/expo-permissions/ios
 expo-sqlite@8.0.0 from ../node_modules/expo-sqlite/ios
 expo-web-browser@8.0.0 from ../node_modules/expo-web-browser/ios
 unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface@5.0.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface/ios
 unimodules-camera-interface@5.0.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-camera-interface/ios
 unimodules-constants-interface@5.0.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-constants-interface/ios
 unimodules-core@5.0.0 from ../node_modules/@unimodules/core/ios
 unimodules-face-detector-interface@5.0.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-face-detector-interface/ios
 unimodules-file-system-interface@5.0.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-file-system-interface/ios
 unimodules-font-interface@5.0.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-font-interface/ios
 unimodules-image-loader-interface@5.0.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-image-loader-interface/ios
 unimodules-permissions-interface@5.0.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-permissions-interface/ios
 unimodules-react-native-adapter@5.0.0 from ../node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/ios
 unimodules-sensors-interface@5.0.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-sensors-interface/ios
 unimodules-task-manager-interface@5.0.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-task-manager-interface/ios

Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `RNGestureHandler` from `../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/RNGestureHandler.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `RNReanimated` from `../node_modules/react-native-reanimated/RNReanimated.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Downloading dependencies
Installing DoubleConversion (1.1.6)
Installing EXAppLoaderProvider (8.0.0)
Installing EXConstants (8.0.0)
Installing EXErrorRecovery (1.0.0)
Installing EXFileSystem (8.0.0)
Installing EXFont (8.0.0)
Installing EXKeepAwake (8.0.0)
Installing EXLinearGradient (8.0.0)
Installing EXLocation (8.0.0)
Installing EXPermissions (8.0.0)
Installing EXSQLite (8.0.0)
Installing EXWebBrowser (8.0.0)
Installing FBLazyVector (0.61.5)
Installing FBReactNativeSpec (0.61.5)
Installing Folly (2018.10.22.00)
Installing RCTRequired (0.61.5)
Installing RCTTypeSafety (0.61.5)
Installing RNGestureHandler (1.5.2)
Installing RNReanimated (1.4.0)
Installing RNScreens (2.0.0-alpha.22)
Installing React (0.61.5)
Installing React-Core (0.61.5)
Installing React-CoreModules (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTActionSheet (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTAnimation (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTBlob (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTImage (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTLinking (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTNetwork (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTSettings (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTText (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTVibration (0.61.5)
Installing React-cxxreact (0.61.5)
Installing React-jsi (0.61.5)
Installing React-jsiexecutor (0.61.5)
Installing React-jsinspector (0.61.5)
Installing ReactCommon (0.61.5)
Installing UMBarCodeScannerInterface (5.0.0)
Installing UMCameraInterface (5.0.0)
Installing UMConstantsInterface (5.0.0)
Installing UMCore (5.0.0)
Installing UMFaceDetectorInterface (5.0.0)
Installing UMFileSystemInterface (5.0.0)
Installing UMFontInterface (5.0.0)
Installing UMImageLoaderInterface (5.0.0)
Installing UMPermissionsInterface (5.0.0)
Installing UMReactNativeAdapter (5.0.0)
Installing UMSensorsInterface (5.0.0)
Installing UMTaskManagerInterface (5.0.0)
Installing Yoga (1.14.0)
Installing boost-for-react-native (1.63.0)
Installing glog (0.3.5)
#!/bin/bash
# Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
#
# This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
# LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.

set -e

PLATFORM_NAME="${PLATFORM_NAME:-iphoneos}"
CURRENT_ARCH="${CURRENT_ARCH}"

if [ -z "$CURRENT_ARCH" ] || [ "$CURRENT_ARCH" == "undefined_arch" ]; then
    # Xcode 10 beta sets CURRENT_ARCH to "undefined_arch", this leads to incorrect linker arg.
    # it's better to rely on platform name as fallback because architecture differs between simulator and device

    if [[ "$PLATFORM_NAME" == *"simulator"* ]]; then
        CURRENT_ARCH="x86_64"
    else
        CURRENT_ARCH="armv7"
    fi
fi

export CC="$(xcrun -find -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME cc) -arch $CURRENT_ARCH -isysroot $(xcrun -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME --show-sdk-path)"
export CXX="$CC"

# Remove automake symlink if it exists
if [ -h "test-driver" ]; then
    rm test-driver
fi

./configure --host arm-apple-darwin

# Fix build for tvOS
cat << EOF >> src/config.h

/* Add in so we have Apple Target Conditionals */
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#include <Availability.h>
#endif

/* Special configuration for AppleTVOS */
#if TARGET_OS_TV
#undef HAVE_SYSCALL_H
#undef HAVE_SYS_SYSCALL_H
#undef OS_MACOSX
#endif

/* Special configuration for ucontext */
#undef HAVE_UCONTEXT_H
#undef PC_FROM_UCONTEXT
#if defined(__x86_64__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__rip
#elif defined(__i386__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__eip
#endif
EOF

# Prepare exported header include
EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR="exported/glog"
mkdir -p exported/glog
cp -f src/glog/log_severity.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/raw_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/stl_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/vlog_is_on.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"

/bin/bash: xcrun: command not found
/bin/bash: xcrun: command not found
: not found: 16: ./configure:
./configure: 32: ./configure: Syntax error: newline unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Comment: Or is it ```xcrun: command not found``` causing issues since I have not got XCode? Not sure what I can do about this. I thought it was still possible using react native to create apps for iOS on Windows